# paragraph template suggestion based on parent content type

Tags: 8, theming, paragraphs

I have two content type using same paragraph as field , though template code will be according to content type. How can i can have different template names for paragraph template depending on content type.

Current naming convention: `paragraph--paragraph-type.html.twig`

Desired naming convention: `paragraph--parent-content-type--paragraph-type.html.twig`

Another solution will be get the url and pass it as variable in template and use template code according to url passed.

Answer (score 9):

Add a theme name suggestion:

*mytheme.theme:*

```
/**
 * Implements hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK_alter().
 */
function mytheme_theme_suggestions_paragraph_alter(&$suggestions, $variables) {
  $paragraph = $variables['elements']['#paragraph'];
  $parent = $paragraph->getParentEntity();
  if ($parent) {
    $suggestions[] = 'paragraph__' . $parent->bundle() . '__' .  $paragraph->bundle();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use different view modes for different node types. On Strcuture > Paragraphs types, add as many different view modes for your paragraph, as needed by your node types. On Structure > Content types, change the display mode for the node's paragraphs field to "Rendered entity" and use the cog wheel to select the previously created, corresponding view mode. Now create template files like paragraph--paragraph-type--viewmode-name.html.twig